# Flutter error, The argument type '' can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter

I keep getting error such as this, can someone explain the what the error mean and what i need to do to prevent them?

```
The argument type 'Future<List<CompanyModel>> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<CompanyModel>> Function(String?)?'.
```

I have a ModelClass and i want to get some values from an api to a searchable dropdown widget.

Below is the widget code

```
                  DropdownSearch<CompanyModel>(
                    label: "Name",
                    onFind: (String filter) async {
                      var response = await Dio().get(
                        "http://5d85ccfb1e61af001471bf60.mockapi.io/user",
                        queryParameters: {"filter": filter},
                      );
                      var models = CompanyModel.fromJsonList(response.data);
                      return models;
                    },
                  ),
```

And my model class, it is quiet long.

```
class CompanyModel {
  final String name;

  CompanyModel({required this.name});

  factory CompanyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CompanyModel(name: json['comapny_name']);
  }

  static List<CompanyModel> fromJsonList(List list) {
    return list.map((item) => CompanyModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
  }
  ///this method will prevent the override of toString
  String userAsString() {
    return '#${this.name}';
  }

  ///custom comparing function to check if two users are equal
  bool isEqual(CompanyModel model) {
    return this?.name == model?.name;
  }

  @override
  String toString() => name;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the `onFind` attribute requires a function with a nullable String as its parameter, you are not passing a nullable String

Try changing this

```
onFind: (String filter) async {
```

to this

```
onFind: (String? filter) async {
```

if this doesn't work you will have to add the code of `DropdownSearch` class so we can get more info